# MATLAB get xyrgb pixel values

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I'm trying to get a five column matrix with one row for each pixel in an image. The first two columns are the location (x,y) of the pixel, and the remaining columns are the RGB values of the pixel.

I can use a loop to create this matrix, but I would like to vectorize this operation for efficiency purposes. I can get the RGB values with img(:,:,1), img(:,:,2), and img(:,:,3) respectively, but I don't know how to get the x and y value of the associated pixel while vectorizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to get all `x` and `y` coordinates and then append these to your data resulting in a `N x 5` matrix.

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:size(img, 2), 1:size(img, 1));
out = cat(2, x(:), y(:), reshape(img, [], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Find`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) is one way to query the coordinates.

You can separate the RGB channels, find the coordinates and then concatenate the results:

```
imgR = img(:, :, 1);
imgG = img(:, :, 2);
imgB = img(:, :, 3);
[rows, cols] = find(imgR + 1); % +1 to avoid zeros!
M = [rows, cols, imgR(:), imgG(:), imgB(:)];
```

Comment: And `find` is anything but fast, especially for tabulating *all* the indices.

Comment: Also the outputs of find are rows and columns respectively, so it's really `[y, x] = find(imgR)` if anything

Comment: @AndrasDeak About the speed you are right, I actually compared with `meshgrid` and I got better results for `find` but it was the case just for small images.

Comment: @Suever I avoided the issue with zeros, thanks for noting. The definition of `x` and `y` is a matter of preference and both are fine. But since we are talking about coordinating in an image, I prefer mine.

Comment: @erfan The mathworks themselves note the difference between [row/column and x/y indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/06/21/indexing-terminology/). x is widely considered to be columns. At the very least, label the outputs of `find` as `[rows, columns]` or something like that so as to avoid confusion.